# Spring boot test unable to autowire service class

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing

I am attempting to create a Spring Boot test class which should create the Spring context and autowire the service class for me to test.

This is the error I am getting:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type
>   'com.gobsmack.gobs.base.service.FileImportService' available: expected
>   at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
>   annotations:
>   {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

The file structue:

[image]

The Test class:

```
package com.example.gobs.base.service;

import com.example.gobs.base.entity.FileImportEntity;
import com.example.gobs.base.enums.FileImportType;
import lombok.val;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import java.util.Date;

import static org.assertj.core.api.AssertionsForClassTypes.assertThat;

@DataJpaTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class FileImportServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private FileImportService fileImportService;

    private FileImportEntity entity;
```

The `Main` application class:

```
package com.example.gobs.base;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

/**
 * Used only for testing.
 */
@SpringBootApplication
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
    }
}
```

`FileImportService` interface:

```
package com.example.gobs.base.service;

import com.example.gobs.base.entity.FileImportEntity;
import com.example.gobs.base.enums.FileImportType;

import java.util.List;

public interface FileImportService {

    /**
     * List all {@link FileImportEntity}s.
```

Which is implemented by:

```
package com.example.gobs.base.service.impl;

import com.example.gobs.base.entity.FileImportEntity;
import com.example.gobs.base.enums.FileImportType;
import com.example.gobs.base.repository.FileImportRepository;
import com.example.gobs.base.service.FileImportService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.List;

@Service
@Transactional
public class FileImportServiceImpl implements FileImportService {

    @Autowired
    private FileImportRepository repository;

    @Override
    public List<FileImportEntity> listAllFileImportsByType(FileImportType type) {
        return repository.findAllByType(type.name());
    }
```

Why can it not find the implementation?

Comment: Because you're using `@DataJpaTest` and it only considers the "data slice" of your application.

Comment: You should probably not use an integration test to test that service. Instead, a simple unit test, where the repository is mocked, would be much easier to write and maintain and much faster to run.

Comment: Ah, the thing is it calls the repository layer. Is there a way to have JPA and the service layer loaded?

Comment: Sure. But why would you want that? One of the main points of having a separate repository layer is to be able to mock it when testing the service layer, so that tests of the service layer don't need a test database with test data in order to be tested.

Comment: So true. I guess I was trying to kill 2 birds with one stone in terms of code coverage. As there is not much business logic in the service class.

Comment: FYI, (but I still don't advise doing that), adding `@Import(FileImportServiceImpl.class)` to your test class should make the service available. You would have a context with all the data layer available, + that specific service.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`@DataJpaTest` annotation doesn't make services loaded to the application context. From Spring documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test

> You can use the @DataJpaTest annotation to test JPA applications. By default, it scans for @Entity classes and configures Spring Data JPA repositories. If an embedded database is available on the classpath, it configures one as well. Regular @Component beans are not loaded into the ApplicationContext.

You could use `@SpringBootTest` annotation instead of `DataJpaTest`. Hope that helps!